# Why do daemons fork?

Tags: daemon, fork

I'm aware some (all?) daemons fork when they're being started. I'm under the impression this is to run the child processes as less privileged users, especially if the daemon is something like a HTTP server.

Why is this necessary though? Couldn't a process start up and drop its privileges without forking a child process? Is it "mandatory" for forking, or is there some other special reason (other than for running multiple child worker processes)?

I'm new to this and would appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think daemons fork for several reasons:

1. One reason is **to detach process from any shell that starts it**.  Some shells (Bash, for instance) kill children upon exit, unless special, shell-specific precautions are made.  Forking is a generic way to evade this.
2. Another reason is **to report that the daemon was successfully started**.

   Assume it doesn't fork.  How would you know that the daemon has been started successfully?  You can't just read and parse daemon output, because daemon management programs should do it in a generic way.  So the only way is to get return code of the program.

   Indeed, if a daemon failed to start (for example, it couldn't find config file), you would know that immediately. But hey, if a daemon has been started successfully, it may never return!  So your daemon manager can't know whether daemon is still trying to start, or has been started, and is working.  Fork would solve the problem, and the forking program would return success if a fork worked well.
3. As for privileges, dropping them **after `execve` is much less secure than doing so before `execve`**.  Here's another reason why fork is handy.

Comment: Little late to the party. Let me address your answer in the context of systemd. For point 1: systemd start's the process up, and doesn't close it. For point 2: if the process exits than systemd consider's it a failed state, and if it keeps running than everything is fine. Given these two points, is it still recommended to use forking for programming daemons running under systemd?

Answer (score 9):

Daemons must fork two times because they must be indipendent of other processes, that is there's no way to kill the daemon killing another process, and must be running in the background, that is not attached to a terminal.

On startup the daemon forks and the parent dies. This makes the forked process a child of `init`, so basically it's indipendent from other processes.

On the second fork the child is no more a process leader, and is detached from the terminal.

Others good practices may apply, reading the source code of a simple daemon may be insightful.

Comment: Any suggestions of a well-written simple daemon to grok?  I'd be willing to bet that there are some to avoid...

Comment: This answer must've been accepted, as it explains the double-forking, which is a very important concept when it comes to daemons.

Answer (score 3):

I was under the impression that this was done to keep the daemon completely unattached to any other processes (like a shell or similar). By forking and exiting the parent process the Orphaned process will be "adopted" by the system init process.

Answer (score 3):

To back up what daramarak said, from [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29):

> In a Unix environment, the parent
>   process of a daemon is often (but not
>   always) the init process (PID=1).
>   Processes usually become daemons by
>   forking a child process and then
>   having their parent process
>   immediately exit, thus causing init to
>   adopt the child process. This is a
>   somewhat simplified view of the
>   process as other operations are
>   generally performed, such as
>   dissociating the daemon process from
>   any controlling tty. Convenience
>   routines such as daemon(3) exist in
>   some UNIX systems for that purpose.

Basically the process needs to disassociate from other processes and from terminals and such.