# How to close fork child-process

Tags: nodes

I am new in nodejs, I was created two process and from first process i am running second process using fork

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
var productionApp = fork("../secondProcess");
```

When i run first process first time second process is also get start.

Now the problem is when i am trying to restart or stop and start first process then i am getting this error:

```
{ [Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::9000]
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 9000 }
```

here port 9000 is in `secondProcess`.
And secondProcess is not stopped when I stopped first process.

So I just wants to know how to stop child-process when parent process is stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow some principles.

The error is obvious, your child process is still using the port and you cannot start a new socket to listen on the same one.

How to solve / avoid this?

1. Your child process should generally not live longer than the parent. Only when your goal is to [demonize a process through forking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192472/why-do-daemons-fork).
2. When starting / stopping, you should create [a lock file with the PIDs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12815/what-are-pid-and-lock-files-for) (process IDs) and only allow a single instance to be executed at all. When you stop the parent process, the children should also be stopped and when you restart the parent, it should warn about still running children.